# InstantiationException on call to method.getReturnType().newInstance(), a static method of a static inner class

Tags: java, object, static-methods, inner-classes

I get

```
run: method: foo
Return type: class java.lang.Integer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Integer
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:359)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
  at newinstancetest.NewInstanceTest.main(NewInstanceTest.java:10)
Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

When I run this:
package newinstancetest;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

```
public class NewInstanceTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method method = InnerClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", null);
    System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());
    System.out.println("Return type: " + method.getReturnType());
    Object obj = method.getReturnType().newInstance();
    System.out.println("obj: " + obj);
}

public static class InnerClass {
    public static Integer foo() {
        return new Integer(1);
    }
}
}
```

Shouldn't the "obj" + obj print the reference to a new object? Any idea why i get an exception instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type for the method is `Integer` which does not have a `no-arg` constructor. To replicate the instance in the foo method, you could do

```
Object obj = method.getReturnType().getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Integer does not have a contructor with no argument. You can use the `Integer(int)` instead for example:

```
Object obj = method.getReturnType().getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(0);
```

If you meant to call the `foo` method, then you can use:

```
Object obj = method.invoke(null); //null for static
```

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, the method `getReturnType()` in

```
Object obj = method.getReturnType().newInstance();
```

returns a `Class<Integer>` instance. The `Integer` class has two constructors, one with `int` and one with `String`.

When you call `newInstance()`, you're expecting the default `no-arg` constructor of the returned class object, which doesn't exist.

You need to get the constructors

```
Constructor[] constructors = d.getReturnType().getConstructors();
```

then iterate and use the one that matches best.